# Artisan fresh command

Tags: laravel-5

How can I remove all the boilerplate included in Laravel 5, such as bootstrap/authentication etc?
In laracasts lessons Jeffrey Way told about `php artisan fresh` command, but there is no such command in stable release

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately after that Laracasts episode was posted - Taylor removed the `fresh` command on Dec 17 2014: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/37ebc7ecc693405a717239ca30e0586d0a71e4d3

For now you'll have to manually delete the files yourself. Or create a pull request to add it back in.

**Update 27th Feb:** As of today the `artisan fresh` command is back in Laravel 5 https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/c69ddcf4941f6b23349b882171c44e0071963647

**Update 9th June:** Sad news, as of Laravel 5.1 `artisan fresh` command is removed again.

Comment: What the hell is going on?

Comment: @s3v3nv - Taylor has said that with 5.1 there is very little boiler plate to remove - so he feels the command is not needed.

Comment: It's not the first time I encounter un-updated stuff on laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0, they should definetively update the docs more frequently...