# what folders and files can I delete from a new Laravel 5 installation

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to remove all folders and files (controllers, models, migration files) which are not required for development. thank you.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do this. Speed?

Comment: Depending on how you develop your app, everything is necessary at some point.  If you want minimal Laravel, use Lumen.

Comment: This just screams bad idea. IMO, the risk of your application failing to start after you remove these files/folders heavily outweighs the benefit you'll see from doing so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `php artisan fresh` will remove any boilerplate like the default auth system, views, controllers, bootstrap, etc.

Comment: Good answer, and congrats for figuring out what the close voters/commenters didn't seem to. :-)

Comment: Some garbage will still exist, like a HomeController and a view, you can remove those as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, `fresh` has been removed in Laravel 5.1; however, you might use the relevant commits as guidelines for what files could be removed directly after a fresh install. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380223/artisan-fresh-command

Comment: Noo, why was `fresh` removed :( .  Hate bloatware

Comment: Well, just saw the source of the fresh command and it's only a handleful of items it deletes. Can quickly do this manually